# Compare string time with current time android

Tags: android, string, time, android-notifications

I have 2 time in string format from timepickerdialog. I can not figure out **how to compare my first string time to current time**. Between time1-time2 period i want to show a simple notification. I have read a lot of documentation with no luck. Maybe a detailed tutorial or source code would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
 final Button time1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);       
    time1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimePickerDialog dpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    Scheduler.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true
            );
            dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
            dpd.setOnTimeSetListener(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout radialPickerLayout, int selectedhour, int selectedminute) {
                    time1.setText(pad(selectedhour) + " : " + pad(selectedminute));      

                }
            });
        }
    });


    final Button time2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);       
    time2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimePickerDialog dpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    Scheduler.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true
            );

            dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
            dpd.setOnTimeSetListener(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout radialPickerLayout, int selectedhour, int selectedminute) {
                    time2.setText(pad(selectedhour) + " : " + pad(selectedminute));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is excellent JodaTime library for time-related operations and it even has an Android flavor, here is a link for you:

https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

In your case, if I get things correctly, you have two points in time (hour and minutes pairs -- HH:MM -- time1 and time2) to compare and you what to make sure that current time is within that range, right?

In this case I'd use JodaTime's [LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class and compare current time to time1 and time2.

It might look like this:

```
LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
LocalTime time1 = new LocalTime(selectedhour1, selectedminute1);
LocalTime time2 = new LocalTime(selectedhour2, selectedminute2);

if (currenTime >= time1 && currentTime <= time2) {
    // show your notification
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! You got it right and it was really helpful.